# Javascript for several elements in a PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, for-loop

I have created a HTML table where every row retrieves data from an sql database table.

```
?>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Activities</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Position</th>
        <th scope="col">Activity Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $incremental=0;
        while($selRow=$res_selPostData->fetch_assoc()) {
            $incremental +=1;
            $filepath='.\outputs\\' . 'verbale' . $selRow['IDIntervento'] . '.pdf'; 
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $selRow['IDActivity']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $selRow['DateActivity']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $selRow['Position']; ?></td>
                <td><div id=<?php echo "TypeAct" . $incremental; ?>><?php echo $selRow['Activity_type']; ?></div></td>
                <td><div id=<?php echo "button" . $incremental; ?>><span id='edit'>EDIT</span></div></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The last column of the HTML table contains for each row a 'button' which is connected to the following javascript function.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
                var maximum=parseInt(<?php echo $incremental; ?>);
                for (let i = 1; i<maximum; i++) {
                    var makeMod = document.getElementById('TypeAct' + 'i');
                    var div = document.getElementById('button' + 'i');
                    div.onclick = function(e) {
                        makeMod.contentEditable = true;
                        makeMod.focus();
                        makeMod.style.backgroundColor = '#E0E0E0';
                        makeMod.style.border = '1px dotted black';
                    }
                }
            }
</script>
```

I had tried using the script without the for loop with

```
<td><div id=<?php echo "button"; ?>><span id='edit'>EDIT</span></div></td>
```

and

```
var makeMod = document.getElementById('TypeAct')` and `var div = document.getElementById('button')
```

but in that case the function works only for one row.

Changing 'i' to i solved the problem with the 'button' but when i click the button in different rows only the activity_type in the last row becomes editable and not the one in the same row as the button; as if the function only acts on the last generated row in the while loop of the table. Can you guess why?

Comment: how is supposed to work when you get the element and concatenate a string 'i' not the value of your `i` variable `var makeMod = document.getElementById('TypeAct' + 'i');` you should change it to this `var makeMod = document.getElementById('TypeAct' + i);`

Comment: That solved the problem with the 'button' but when i click the button in different rows only the activity_type in the last row becomes editable and not the one in the same row as the button; as if the function only acts on the last generated row in the while loop of the table. Can you guess why?

Comment: another issue: ids are unique and this part of your code is inside a loop, you can't have multiple elements with the same id, so change it like you did with your other ids `<span id='edit'>EDIT</span>`

Comment: Is this **really** a PHP problem? Why not generate static markup first, get it running with all that JS logic, and buld the markup dynamically afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im using a sample HTML with sample data I made just to test the code, since PHP can't be reproduced in here so.

1. First thing first, replace the string `i` with the variable (which you already did)

   `makeMod = document.getElementById('TypeAct-' + i);`
2. This line of code is inside a loop. `<span id='edit'>EDIT</span>` which means you will have multiple elements with the `edit` id. Can't have that so change it like you did with the other ids. You can concatenate your php variable `$incremental` like you did with the others.
3. Change your loop to this `for (let i = 1; i <= maximum; i++) {` if you leave it to `i < maximum` then it won't add the event to your last button.
4. It is much better to use `let` and `const` instead of `var` now. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)
5. Use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`. Why? read more about it here [addEventListener-vs-onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick#:%7E:text=Summary%3A,can%20stop%20the%20event%20propagation.)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let maximum = 3;//sample value, leave this line like in your original code
  let makeMod;
  for (let i = 1; i <= maximum; i++) {
    document.getElementById('button-' + i).addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      makeMod = document.getElementById('TypeAct-' + i);
      makeMod.contentEditable = true;
      makeMod.focus();
      makeMod.style.backgroundColor = '#E0E0E0';
      makeMod.style.border = '1px dotted black';
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Activities</h2>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Position</th>
        <th scope="col">Activity Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>
          <div id="TypeAct-1">act 1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="button-1"><span id='edit-1'>EDIT</span></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>
          <div id="TypeAct-2">act 2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="button-2"><span id='edit-2'>EDIT</span></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>
          <div id="TypeAct-3">act 3</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="button-3"><span id='edit-3'>EDIT</span></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That solved the problem completely! Thank you very much

Comment: glad it helped, please accept the answer and vote up is also appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
var div = document.getElementById('button' + 'i');
```

the 'i' is in quotes, thus not getting the calculated value but literally the letter "i". Instead, try:

```
var div = document.getElementById('button' + i);
```

and ideally use a hyphen between the word button and the increment variable like:

```
id="button-1" id="button-2" etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better, IMO, to remove the ID attributes entirely if you need to use a numerical suffix to help identify elements and rely on other, more flexible means of identifying DOM elements, such as `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll` and other parent/child/sibling type properties & methods. In the above the only use that the PHP variable `$incremental` has is as that numeric suffix - it would play no part in whatever actual `edit` operation (Form submission/ ajax etc) when the record is to be edited so could be removed.  The table is generated with content from a database so you have an `IDActivity` which will be useful in an edit operation so assign that as the data-id value!

The identifying of `click` events can be done using a `delegated event listener` rather than assigning an event listener to each `button`.

I also added a `blur` event handler to the contentEditable DIV elements that returns  them to their normal state when no longer used. That `blur` handler could be used to fire off the ajax request to edit the record in db.

```js
const d=document;
const CN='editable';

d.querySelector('.container table').addEventListener('click', e=>{
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLSpanElement && e.target.dataset.type == 'edit' ) {
    let id=e.target.parentNode.dataset.id;
    let content = e.target.parentNode.closest('tr').querySelector('div[data-type="content"]');
        content.contentEditable=true;
        content.focus();
        content.classList.add( CN );
        
    console.log( ' -> Id=%s',id )
  }
});

d.querySelectorAll('[data-type="content"]').forEach(n=>n.addEventListener('blur',e=>{
  if( e.target.classList.contains( CN ) ){
    e.target.classList.remove( CN );
    e.target.contentEditable=false;
    
    // update using ajax?
    console.log(e.target.dataset.id,e.target.textContent);
  }
}));
```

```css
.editable{
  background:#E0E0E0;
  border:1px dotted black
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Activities</h2>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Position</th>
        <th scope="col">Activity Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- emulated content -->
      <!--
        The `IDActivity` value is what would be assigned
        to the `data-id` attribute below. That `data-id`
        is easily accessible in Javascript and can be used
        for whatever EDIT operation you wish.
        
        ie: 
        <td>
          <div data-id="<?=$selRow['IDActivity'];?>">
            <?=$selRow['Activity_type'];?>
          </div>
        </td>
      -->
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2023/04/15</td>
        <td>Midfield</td>
        <td><div data-id=1 data-type='content'>Banana Bouncing</div></td>
        <td><div data-id=1><span data-type='edit'>EDIT</span></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2023/04/17</td>
        <td>Ground-Level</td>
        <td><div data-id=2 data-type='content'>Hedgehog Juggling</div></td>
        <td><div data-id=2><span data-type='edit'>EDIT</span></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2023/04/18</td>
        <td>Upstairs</td>
        <td><div data-id=3 data-type='content'>Dwarf Tossing</div></td>
        <td><div data-id=3><span data-type='edit'>EDIT</span></div></td>
      </tr>
      <!-- end emulated content -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```